# How to convince fancyvrb to give overfull warnings?

Tags: fancyvrb

The following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\hsize=1cm
\begin{Verbatim}
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

does *not* give a warning. But I *do* want to see when something is bigger than it is supposed to be. What can I do?

(The Verbatim environment is produced by pygmentize, so I'd prefer a solution that does not involve changing it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}
```

at least during testing. However, some options for `Verbatim` do not apply to `BVerbatim`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, just to help any future readers.

`fancyvrb` uses something like `\hbox to \linewidth{<content of a line>\hss}` to print every verbatim line. It is the `\hss` that prohibits an overfull `\hbox` message. Change the `\hss` to `\hfil`, i.e., to remove the shrinkability but keep stretchability may help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\FV@ListProcessLine#1{%
  \hbox to \hsize{%
    \kern\leftmargin
    \hbox to \linewidth{%
      \FV@LeftListNumber
      \FV@LeftListFrame
      \FancyVerbFormatLine{#1}\hfil % change \hss to \hfil
      \FV@RightListFrame
      \FV@RightListNumber}%
    \hss}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newlength{\xhsize}
\settowidth{\xhsize}{\texttt{foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar}}

\hsize=\xhsize

No overfull hbox
\begin{Verbatim}
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
\end{Verbatim}

\hsize=\xhsize
\advance\hsize -10pt

Overfull hbox 10pt
\begin{Verbatim}
foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```